# How to calculate discount in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple database having some fields. fields are as follows: id,product_name,original_price, discount
the discount field is in percentage. 
I am fetching all the data once using Axios and rendering on the page using `v-for`
code:

```
<ul v-for="product in products">
   <li>@{{product.product_name}}</li>
   <li>@{{product.original_price}}</li>
   <li>@{{product.discount}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here I want to display calculated price after discount. i could create a method in a Vue instance 
like this:

```
      calculateDiscount: function(orig_price, discount){
                         this.discount_amt = discount/100*orig_price;
                         return this.after_discount = orig_price - this.discount_amt;
    }
```

if i create this method how can i call this method while rendering please help.

Comment: You can do this via computed property insted method, thats what computed properties are made.

Comment: @FarrukhAyyaz Thanks for the answer. I am new at Vue Js. Could you please show me how can achieve this?

Comment: computed: { discounted() { return this.product_price - this.discount } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a computed property because you need a calculation on each product in products and computed property can't take any parameter.
You can use method instead :

```
<ul v-for="product in products">
  <li>@{{product.product_name}}</li>
  <li>@{{product.original_price}}</li>
  <li>@{{product.discount}}</li>
  <li>@{{ discountedPrice(product) }}</li>
</ul>


methods: {
  discountedPrice(product) {
    return product.original_price - (product.original_price *(product.discount)/100)
  }
}
```

Comment: I've put together a JSFiddle example of this so you can see it in action. https://jsfiddle.net/DerekFulginiti/hzy7e3o7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Do that calculation in your server side and just assign the **after_discount** as final discount in each product and you can display the discount like below.

```
   <ul v-for="product in products">
       <li>@{{product.product_name}}</li>
       <li>@{{product.original_price}}</li>
       <li>@{{product.discount}}</li>
       <li>@{{product.after_discount}}</li>
   </ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. is there any other way? i mean the VUE WAY ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      list: [{
        product_name: 'name',
        original_price: 300,
        discount: 8.5
      },{
        product_name: 'name',
        original_price: 1200,
        discount: 7.5
      },{
        product_name: 'name',
        original_price: 3000,
        discount: 5.5
      }]
    }
  },
  filters: {
    priceAfterDiscount (v,discount) {
      return (v * discount / 10).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <ul v-for="item of list">
      <li>product: {{item.product_name}}</li>
      <li>price: {{item.original_price}}</li>
      <li>discount: {{item.discount}}</li>
      <li>priceAfterDiscount: {{item.original_price | priceAfterDiscount(item.discount)}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```